# jquery autocomplete plugin does not submit values to server

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using this plugin: http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

I have an autocomplete textarea where the values are autocompleted and are separated by commas.

This textarea is inside a form.  When I submit this form, I expect the values to be transmitted to the serverside which is the action of my form.  However, I am not getting any values back.

How can I fix that?

Here is my code:

jQuery autocomplete code:

```
jQueryTest("#newImages").autocomplete("images.php", {
    width: 320,
    max: 3,
    highlight: false,
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 200,
    multiple: true,             
    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
        return "<img height='72' width='72' src='/catalogFiles/" + 
        value + ".jpg'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
    },
    formatResult: function(data, value) {
        return value.split(".")[0];
    },
});
```

Html:

```
<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">   
   <td style="padding-right: 25px;">New Images:</td>
   <td><textarea class="inputmeat" name="newImages_name" rows="3" cols="60" 
     id="newImages"></textarea></td>
   <td style="padding-right: 25px;"></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Update" /></td>
</form>
```

PHP Code when submit is clicked:

```
<?php
$cmd=$_POST["cmd"]; 
if(isset($cmd)) {
     $newImagesName = mysql_escape_string( $_POST["newImages_name"]);   
     echo $newImageName;  
}
?>
```

Comment: Start by showing us some code, so we can see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo, either in your code or on this page?

```
$newImagesName = mysql_escape_string( $_POST["newImages_name"]);   
echo $newImageName;
```

Note, `newImagesName` vs. `newImageName`.

Comment: :( I guess its time for me to call it a night. thanks for pointing tha tout for me!